# OfficeJS addin, ribbon icons not showing on Mac

Tags: excel, macos, office-js, manifest

I've created a simple add-in for Excel by using OfficeJS.

Everything worked fine when I've tried to use it on a Windows machine and on Excel for Web (in chrome browser).

When I tried to use the add-in on a Mac the add-in worked but I couldn't see the ribbon icons.

I thought that the icon was corrupted as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53367657/1726419
so I've used the icon from the template example - it still didn't work.

any suggestions?

Excel for web - we can see the icon:
[image: Excel for web - we can see the icon]

Excel for mac - no icon:
[image: Excel for mac - no icon]

Comment: have your tried different mac pc ?

Comment: @Ahmedaminshahin Yes, It's still not working

Comment: whats the image type ?? @yossico

Comment: is it png or ico or jpg ?

Comment: @Ahmedaminshahin it was PNGs but see my answer - it was a certificate issue... thanks.

Comment: Nice one glad you found the solution

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to self-signed certificates, Excel for Mac not displaying ribbon images if they are not signed with proper CA.

The Web and Windows versions work and also display icons from HTTP (not HTTPS) but again - in Mac, you must have a good certificate.

After moving the server to use a certificate that was signed properly the icons in the ribbon were also displayed properly.

last note, the images in the task-pane displayed properly even though I had a self-signed certificate.

I hope it will help someone to get less frustrated.